# Hide div when looking at page on Android or Apple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to make it so that a div hides or doesnt display when im on android.

I am using the code here http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/xHA46/

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){       
var agent = navigator.userAgent;      
var isAndroid = (agent.indexOf("Android")  > 0);     

if (isAndroid ){ 
    $("div.instruction").show();
}    
});
```

But im unsure how to make it hide instead of show.

Do i just put hide() instead of show() ?

Comment: Part of being a programmer is trying things out. I'm surprised you didn't try your idea out. What would be so bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use `.hide()`.

Read http://api.jquery.com/hide/ for more information.